# Having T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error in PHP/MySQL connectivity

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a class that will ease connectivity with MySQL but I'm getting a T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error. I believe it has something to do with strings but I do not find anything wrong.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php
class mysql
{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $pass;
    private $connection;
    private $database;
    private $result;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this -> $host = 'localhost';
        $this -> $user = 'root';
        $this -> $pass = '';
    }

    public function connect($_host, $_user, $_pass)
    {
        if (isset('$_host')) $this -> $host = $_host;
        if (isset('$_user')) $this -> $user = $_user;
        if (isset('$_pass')) $this -> $pass = $_pass;
        $this -> disconnect();
        $this -> $connection = mysql_connect($this -> $server, $this -> $user, $this -> $pass);
        if (! $this -> $connection) return mysql_error();
        else return true;
    }

    public function isconnected()
    {
        if(is_resource($this -> $connection) && get_resource_type($this -> $connection) === 'mysql link') return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public function disconnect()
    {
        if ($this -> isconnected()) mysql_close($this -> $connection);
    }

    private function setdb($_dbname)
    {
        $this -> $database = $_dbname;
        if (! mysql_select_db($this -> $database, $this -> $connection)) return mysql_error();
        else return true;
    }

    public function runquery($_query)
    {
        if(! isset($database)) return mysql_error();
        else return mysql_query($_query,$this -> $connection);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this -> disconnect();
        unset($this -> $host);
        unset($this -> $user);
        unset($this -> $pass);
        unset($this -> $connection);            
        unset($this -> $database);
        unset($this -> $result);
    }
}

$phpmyadmin = new mysql();
echo $phpmyadmin.connect('localhost','root','');
echo $phpmyadmin.setdb('DBTEST');
$result = $phpmyadmin.runquery("SELECT * FROM TABTEST");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['PERSON_NAME'];
}
?>
```

The error that I get is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\mysql\mysql.php on line 20
```

Line 20 is clearly:

```
if (isset('$_host')) $this -> $host = $_host;
```

What could be wrong?

Edit:
Thanks. I corrected the syntax error but it appears to give me a new error:
    Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\mysql\mysql.php on line 13

Comment: That's not how you use [`isset`](http://us.php.net/isset). Try `isset($_host)`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I'm getting another error:    Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\mysql\mysql.php on line 13

Comment: Every syntax error question is a too localized one

Comment: Change all your `$this->$<variable>` to `$this-><variable>` ie remove the `$` after the `->`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing your second problem:

You should remove the `$` after the `->`, like this:

```
$this->$host
```

should be:

```
$this->host
```

Comment: Also true.  While `$this->$host` is valid, it's probably not desired based on the semantics of this code.

Answer (score 2):

`isset` (as well as `empty`) are language constructs and not functions, and they have a unique property -- to improve speed, the interpreter only allows them to be used on variables (or keys of variable arrays).  As such, you cannot use `isset` or `empty` on anything that's not a variable.  It's actually a syntax error.

```
... isset($host) ...
```